# errors in setting up pylint in Vscode on Mac

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using vsode 1.49.1  on Mac.
I am trying to install pylint in a virtual environment (3.8.2), but I keep having errors. Pylint was installed on a global env, but it cannot be installed in the virtual. Can you help me how to solve it? I also read that I can use the global lint in the virtual env by setting up the path in the setting file. However, I have no idea how to find the path of the global pylint. Can you please give me some insights?

```
Collecting pylint
  Using cached pylint-2.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (325 kB)
Collecting astroid<=2.5,>=2.4.0
  Using cached astroid-2.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (213 kB)
Collecting mccabe<0.7,>=0.6
  Using cached mccabe-0.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.6 kB)
Collecting toml>=0.7.1
  Using cached toml-0.10.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Collecting isort<6,>=4.2.5
  Using cached isort-5.5.3-py3-none-any.whl (95 kB)
Collecting wrapt~=1.11
  Using cached wrapt-1.12.1.tar.gz (27 kB)
Collecting lazy-object-proxy==1.4.*
  Using cached lazy-object-proxy-1.4.3.tar.gz (34 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting six~=1.12
  Using cached six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: wrapt, lazy-object-proxy
  Building wheel for wrapt (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Volumes/ncData/GIT/A4DataReader/.venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/hv/xrpk1szs4mv2rjlvys1gycrw0000gn/T/pip-install-fpdfi9uq/wrapt/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/hv/xrpk1szs4mv2rjlvys1gycrw0000gn/T/pip-install-fpdfi9uq/wrapt/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/hv/xrpk1szs4mv2rjlvys1gycrw0000gn/T/pip-wheel-nkurxfl1
       cwd: /private/var/folders/hv/xrpk1szs4mv2rjlvys1gycrw0000gn/T/pip-install-fpdfi9uq/wrapt/
  Complete output (57 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/wrapt
  copying src/wrapt/importer.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/wrapt
  copying src/wrapt/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/wrapt
  copying src/wrapt/wrappers.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/wrapt
  copying src/wrapt/decorators.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/wrapt
  running build_ext
  building 'wrapt._wrappers' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/src
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/src/wrapt
  xcrun -sdk macosx clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -I/Volumes/ncData/GIT/A4DataReader/.venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c src/wrapt/_wrappers.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/src/wrapt/_wrappers.o
  xcrun -sdk macosx clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -Wl,-headerpad,0x1000 -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/src/wrapt/_wrappers.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/wrapt/_wrappers.cpython-38-darwin.so
  installing to build/bdist.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64/wheel
  running install
  running install_lib
  creating build/bdist.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64
  creating build/bdist.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64/wheel
  creating build/bdist.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64/wheel/wrapt
  copying build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/wrapt/_wrappers.cpython-38-darwin.so -> build/bdist.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64/wheel/wrapt
  copying build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/wrapt/importer.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64/wheel/wrapt
  copying build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/wrapt/__init__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64/wheel/wrapt
  copying build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/wrapt/wrappers.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64/wheel/wrapt
  copying build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/wrapt/decorators.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64/wheel/wrapt
  running install_egg_info
  running egg_info
  creating src/wrapt.egg-info
  writing src/wrapt.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to src/wrapt.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to src/wrapt.egg-info/top_level.txt
  writing manifest file 'src/wrapt.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest file 'src/wrapt.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  writing manifest file 'src/wrapt.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  Copying src/wrapt.egg-info to build/bdist.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64/wheel/wrapt-1.12.1-py3.8.egg-info
  running install_scripts
  [WARNING] This wheel needs a higher macOS version than the version your Python interpreter is compiled against.  To silence this warning, set MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to at least 11_0 or recreate these files with lower MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET:
  build/bdist.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64/wheel/wrapt/_wrappers.cpython-38-darwin.soTraceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/private/var/folders/hv/xrpk1szs4mv2rjlvys1gycrw0000gn/T/pip-install-fpdfi9uq/wrapt/setup.py", line 102, in <module>
      run_setup(with_extensions=True)
    File "/private/var/folders/hv/xrpk1szs4mv2rjlvys1gycrw0000gn/T/pip-install-fpdfi9uq/wrapt/setup.py", line 72, in run_setup
      setup(**setup_kwargs_tmp)
    File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/Volumes/ncData/GIT/A4DataReader/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 328, in run
      impl_tag, abi_tag, plat_tag = self.get_tag()
    File "/Volumes/ncData/GIT/A4DataReader/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 278, in get_tag
      assert tag in supported_tags, "would build wheel with unsupported tag {}".format(tag)
  AssertionError: would build wheel with unsupported tag ('cp38', 'cp38', 'macosx_11_0_x86_64')
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for wrapt
  Running setup.py clean for wrapt
  Building wheel for lazy-object-proxy (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Volumes/ncData/GIT/A4DataReader/.venv/bin/python /Volumes/ncData/GIT/A4DataReader/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py build_wheel /var/folders/hv/xrpk1szs4mv2rjlvys1gycrw0000gn/T/tmpyqd7amlu
       cwd: /private/var/folders/hv/xrpk1szs4mv2rjlvys1gycrw0000gn/T/pip-install-fpdfi9uq/lazy-object-proxy
  Complete output (72 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/lazy_object_proxy
  copying src/lazy_object_proxy/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/lazy_object_proxy
  copying src/lazy_object_proxy/_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/lazy_object_proxy
  copying src/lazy_object_proxy/slots.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/lazy_object_proxy
  copying src/lazy_object_proxy/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/lazy_object_proxy
  copying src/lazy_object_proxy/utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/lazy_object_proxy
  copying src/lazy_object_proxy/simple.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/lazy_object_proxy
  running build_ext
  building 'lazy_object_proxy.cext' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/src
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/src/lazy_object_proxy
  xcrun -sdk macosx clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Isrc/lazy_object_proxy -I/Volumes/ncData/GIT/A4DataReader/.venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c src/lazy_object_proxy/cext.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/src/lazy_object_proxy/cext.o
  xcrun -sdk macosx clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -Wl,-headerpad,0x1000 -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/src/lazy_object_proxy/cext.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/lazy_object_proxy/cext.cpython-38-darwin.so
  installing to build/bdist.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64/wheel
  running install
  running install_lib
  creating build/bdist.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64
  creating build/bdist.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64/wheel
  creating build/bdist.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64/wheel/lazy_object_proxy
  copying build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/lazy_object_proxy/compat.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64/wheel/lazy_object_proxy
  copying build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/lazy_object_proxy/_version.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64/wheel/lazy_object_proxy
  copying build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/lazy_object_proxy/slots.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64/wheel/lazy_object_proxy
  copying build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/lazy_object_proxy/__init__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64/wheel/lazy_object_proxy
  copying build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/lazy_object_proxy/utils.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64/wheel/lazy_object_proxy
  copying build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/lazy_object_proxy/cext.cpython-38-darwin.so -> build/bdist.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64/wheel/lazy_object_proxy
  copying build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/lazy_object_proxy/simple.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64/wheel/lazy_object_proxy
  running install_egg_info
  running egg_info
  writing src/lazy_object_proxy.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to src/lazy_object_proxy.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to src/lazy_object_proxy.egg-info/top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'src/lazy_object_proxy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  writing manifest file 'src/lazy_object_proxy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  Copying src/lazy_object_proxy.egg-info to build/bdist.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64/wheel/lazy_object_proxy-1.4.3-py3.8.egg-info
  running install_scripts
  [WARNING] This wheel needs a higher macOS version than the version your Python interpreter is compiled against.  To silence this warning, set MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to at least 11_0 or recreate these files with lower MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET:
  build/bdist.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64/wheel/lazy_object_proxy/cext.cpython-38-darwin.soTraceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Volumes/ncData/GIT/A4DataReader/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
      main()
    File "/Volumes/ncData/GIT/A4DataReader/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/Volumes/ncData/GIT/A4DataReader/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 204, in build_wheel
      return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
    File "/private/var/folders/hv/xrpk1szs4mv2rjlvys1gycrw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-chypvtmb/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 216, in build_wheel
      return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
    File "/private/var/folders/hv/xrpk1szs4mv2rjlvys1gycrw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-chypvtmb/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 202, in _build_with_temp_dir
      self.run_setup()
    File "/private/var/folders/hv/xrpk1szs4mv2rjlvys1gycrw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-chypvtmb/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 253, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
    File "/private/var/folders/hv/xrpk1szs4mv2rjlvys1gycrw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-chypvtmb/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 145, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 61, in <module>
      setup(
    File "/private/var/folders/hv/xrpk1szs4mv2rjlvys1gycrw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-chypvtmb/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/private/var/folders/hv/xrpk1szs4mv2rjlvys1gycrw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-chypvtmb/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 328, in run
      impl_tag, abi_tag, plat_tag = self.get_tag()
    File "/private/var/folders/hv/xrpk1szs4mv2rjlvys1gycrw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-chypvtmb/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 278, in get_tag
      assert tag in supported_tags, "would build wheel with unsupported tag {}".format(tag)
  AssertionError: would build wheel with unsupported tag ('cp38', 'cp38', 'macosx_11_0_x86_64')
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lazy-object-proxy
Failed to build wrapt lazy-object-proxy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for lazy-object-proxy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Comment: find the location of your python executable and there will be pylint.